# Is it correct "Will ask more questions if needed required"?

Tags: grammar

I wrote in a mail

> Hi ABC,
>
> Thanks for providing helpful information. Will ask more questions if needed required.

Is this statement correct? Please help

Comment: Needed and required are synonyms. Using both of them is a pleonasm, so use either _needed_ or _required_, not both. Maybe you would like to have a look at our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Perhaps you meant _if need arises_

Comment: @mplungjan, if need arises seems good, but Is it correct to write to client mail?

Comment: Sure. Your message is very terse.
_Dear ABC,_
_Thank you for providing me with helpful information. I would like to ask more questions when need arises if I may._

Answer (score 1):

No it is not, I suggest the following:

> Will ask more questions if needed
>
> Will ask more questions if required